Three Way Partitioning
The threeway partitioning problem which uses a left, mid and right pointer to swap the values for numbers which are less than lowVal between lowVal and highVal and greater than highVal. It is not working correctly for one of the testcase which I am going through right now. The issue is I am not sure with the algorithm or with the test case.
arr[] = {1, 14, 5, 20, 4, 2, 54, 20, 87, 98, 3, 1, 32}
lowVal = 1 and highVal = 3


All elements smaller than lowRange come first. 2) All elements in range lowVal to highRange come next. 3) All elements greater than highRange appear in the end.

The Output should be:
[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 54, 20, 87, 98, 20, 5, 32, 14]

But the three pointer dutch flag algorithm way gives the output:
[1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 54, 20, 87, 98, 20, 5, 32, 14]

You can see in the output 2 is after 3 which I think is wrong because it should be between 1 and 3. Please let me know your thoughts on this. I have attached the code for reference.
def threeway(self, nums, lowVal, highVal):
    l, m, r = 0, 0, len(nums) - 1
    
    while m <= r:
        if nums[m] < lowVal:
            nums[m], nums[l] = nums[l], nums[m]
            l += 1
            m += 1
        elif nums[m] > highVal:
            nums[m], nums[r] = nums[r], nums[m]
            r -= 1
        else:
            m += 1
            
    return nums


Why is it wrong? If your middle range is defined as 1<=x<=3 then as long as the values 1,1,2,3 are before the larger elements in some order (even something like 3,1,2,1), that should be acceptable.

Does this answer your question? Three way partitioning of an array

The only reason to expect 2 to precede 3 is that 2 appears before 3 in the input, but partitioning algorithms are not, in general, stable (which is part of why they can be so fast).

Okay Understood. The algorithm is not perfect but the partitioning is a way to understand three pointers concept which are needed to problems like sort colors

this function is partitioning array so it's ok, maybe reference implementation have difference in compariosons like > instead of >= or while is going from end to beginning, either way it's splitting so you are interested in proper chunking which is fine in sorting
this produces desired output
def threeway(nums, lowVal, highVal):
    l, m, r = 0, 0, len(nums) - 1
    while nums[l] < lowVal:
        l += 1
    while nums[r] > highVal:
        r -= 1
    m = l
    while m <= r and l < r:
        if nums[m] < lowVal:
            nums[m], nums[l] = nums[l], nums[m]
            l += 1
        elif nums[m] > highVal:
            nums[m], nums[r] = nums[r], nums[m]
            r -= 1
        else:
            m += 1
            
    return nums

not sure about comparisons so check these

{1, 14, 5, 20, 4, 2, 54, 20, 87, 98, 3, 1, 32} , lowVal = 14 , highVal = 20
But in this test case i doesn't work. It gives the output
[1, 3, 2, 4, 20, 5, 1, 20, 14, 54, 87, 98, 32] instead of
{1, 5, 4, 2, 1, 3, 14, 20, 20, 98, 87, 32, 54}
While 20 should not be before 14.
So the problem is it's either working in one or other test case. Not all of the test cases are working
